# Tensorflow - setting EvalSpec

Tags: python, tensorflow, evaluation

I am new to tensorflow and do not have a good understanding of the [`EvalSpec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/EvalSpec). I don't understand the concept of evaluation steps. I thought once we have learned (or partially learned) the model, we evaluate **each** data point in the validation/evaluation dataset. Does this mean that if we have `x` number of evaluation rows then we should specify `eval steps = x`?

Is there a guideline to select the values for eval steps? Does it depend on the number of worker instances, or the number of rows in the evaluation set?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the API documentation for that class is very poor. There is more information in the [code comments](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L208), saying:

> `steps`: `Int`. Positive number of steps for which to evaluate model. If `None`, evaluates until `input_fn` raises an end-of-input exception. See `Estimator.evaluate` for details.

It sounds like you are doing some distributed training. There is a lot of information under the [`train_and_evaluate`](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L271) function code comments, but in particular you should read [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L338) portion about distributed environments.

Answer (score 1):

One evaluation step is similar to consuming one item from your evaluation `input_fn` which should be outputting batches of data. So in this case the number of steps should be approximately `num_eval_rows/batch_size`.

If you are training locally you can simply set the step parameter to `None` and just have your `input_fn` not repeat over your data so it terminates at one epoch. In the distributed case this behavior is not necessarily supported so you will have to set the number of steps appropriately.